# Calling different screen thru button from a screen

Tags: java, listener

Hello I would like to ask how can I call my Main menu screen from `MainScreen`? and kindly explain a little more details about `Listener`.

below is my prepared code:

```
public class MainScreen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        placeComponents(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {
        JLabel WelcomeNote = new JLabel("Welcome");
        panel.add(WelcomeNote);
        JButton Start = new JButton("Start");
        panel.add(Start);
        //Insert action for Start button here
    }
}


public class MainMenu {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        placeComponents(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {
        JLabel menuLbl = new JLabel("Main Menu");
        panel.add(menuLbl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute a java program from another ? You got 2 void main()

Answer (score 0):

**What is wrong?**

You cannot have two main methods in a single file in Java.

---

**Program**

Here is a demo program to change windows.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

class First extends JFrame
{
    JLabel jlb = new JLabel("Label in First Window");
    JButton jb = new JButton("Next Window");
    First()
    {
        super("First Windows");
        //Set this frame
        this.setSize(350,250);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Setting size of components
        jlb.setBounds(10,10,200,40);
        jb.setBounds(10,120,150,40);
        add(jlb);
        add(jb);

        jb.addActionListener((e)->{
            this.setVisible(false);
            new Second();
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Second extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel jlb = new JLabel("Label in Second Window");
    JButton jb = new JButton("Prev. Window");
    Second()
    {
        super("Second Window");
        this.setSize(350,250);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Setting size of components
        jlb.setBounds(10,10,200,40);
        jb.setBounds(10,120,150,40);
        add(jlb);
        add(jb);

        jb.addActionListener(this);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        this.setVisible(false);
        new First();
    }
}

class StartHere
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = ()->{
            new First();
        };
        r.run();
    }
}
```

---

**Understanding the above program.**

The StartHere class has a main method. It is just used for calling the first window you like. I could even call Second using `new Second()`.

First and Second are similar codes.
Both of them have buttons. On each button (or JButton) I have added a method named `addActionListner(this)`. This method fires up an *ActionEvent* which as you can see in Second class is captured by *actionPerformed* method. This method is declared in *Functional Interface*, *ActionListener*. The *'this'* passed in Second class is you telling where the *actionPerformed* method is present in your code. The parameter is an *ActionListener*. Hence, you have to implement *ActionListener* for the class where you define *actionPerformed*.

---

**Bonus**

The *First* class doesn't seem to follow the norms described above. I passed a strange syntax. It is a new feature included in Java 8.

See this Oracle tutorial about [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).